# Exportar Subsite Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

tenho um sistema Multisite no meu wordpress, e preciso exportar um subsite (site filho) para um outro servidor, via FTP, como faço isso? é possivel ?

Comment: Dẽ uma olhada nesse projeto: https://github.com/10up/MU-Migration ele faz isso.

Answer (score -1):

É sim. Atraves do programa FileZilla você consegue.
Você só vai precisar do host, nome de usuário, senha e porta.